# Get string after the last comma or the last number using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get the string after the last comma or last number using regex for this examples:

- "Flat 1, Asker Horse Sports", -- get string after "," result: "Asker
  Horse Sports"
- "9 Walkers Barn" -- get string after "9" result:
  Walkers Barn

I need that regex to support both cases or to different regex rules, each / case.

I tried `/,[^,]*$/` and `(.*),[^,]*$` to get the strings after the last comma but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
[^,\d\s][^,\d]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IbGZsW/1) (and a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%2C%5Cd%5Cs%5D%5B%5E%2C%5Cd%5D*%5Cr%3F%24&i=Flat%201%2C%20Asker%20Horse%20Sports%0D%0A9%20Walkers%20Barn&o=m)).

**Details**

- `[^,\d\s]` - any char but a comma, digit and whitespace
- `[^,\d]*` - any char but a comma and digit
- `$` - end of string.

In C#, you may also tell the regex engine to search for the match from the end of the string with the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option (to make regex matching more efficient. although it might not be necessary in this case if the input strings are short):

```
var output = Regex.Match(text, @"[^,\d\s][^,\d]*$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)?.Value;
```

Comment: Why the whitespace in the first part?

Comment: Okay, I think I got, to basically .TrimStart() the result.

Comment: @RandRandom Well, `Regex.Match(text, @"[^,\d]+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)?.Value.Trim()` would work, too.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track the capture group in `(.*),[^,]*$`, but the group should be the part that you are looking for.

If there has to be a comma or digit present, you could match until the last occurrence of either of them, and capture what follows in the capturing group.

```
^.*[\d,]\s*(.+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `[\d,]` Match either `,` or a digit
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.+)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%5b%5cd%2c%5d%5cs*%28.%2b%29%5cr%3f%24&i=Flat+1%2c+Asker+Horse+Sports%0d%0a9+Walkers+Barn&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ZdL15v)

[image]

Comment: Did not know that you can have multiple groups of marches. Great example. Thank you.